# Position the type-able area in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

By default, the type-able area of a UITextField get positioned "vertical-center", like so

[image]

How can I get the type-able area to be positioned to the bottom but with a padding/offset from the bottom ?

Comment: Try using contentVerticalAlignment. You can set this to center, top, bottom, or fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `textRectForBounds(_:)`, `placeholderRectForBounds(_:)` and `editingRectForBounds(_:)` methods of `UITextField` to customize the text position and combine with `contentVerticalAlignment` set to `.Bottom`.

Say that you want your text to have 10 points padding:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var padding: CGFloat = 10.0

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      contentVerticalAlignment = .Bottom  
    }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

      return CGRectInset(bounds, padding, padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

      return self.textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

      return self.textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. Spent quite a bit of time getting this to work - I did not considering pairing the "Alignment" as well. I was just trying to figure things out with the Rect alone.